# Google thin fonts are not readable in windows safari, how can I fix it?

Tags: html, css, windows, fonts, safari

I have used Google thin font([Shadows Into Light Two](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Shadows+Into+Light+Two)) in my website. When i tested this with windows safari, it's shows unreadable. Other Windows browsers and Mac safari working fine.

**Menu in Windows Safari**

[image: Menu in Windows Safari]

**Menu in Windows Other Browsers(IE,FF,Chrome...etc) and Mac Safari**

[image: Menu in Windows Other Browsers(IE,FF,Chrome...etc)]

This is working but it's browser settings.
https://forums.adobe.com/message/5751340#5751340

This solution not working for me.
[Font weight turns lighter on Mac/Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21278020/font-weight-turns-lighter-on-mac-safari)

Answer (score 0):

Just curious; Did you download the font and imported it to your website or linked to it from Google Fonts? Don't ask me why - but in the past (quite some time ago though) - I used the same font first on my server and it looked ugly, like your example - then I linked to it from some random website and it was all nice-y looking.

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shadows+Into+Light+Two' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

font-family: 'Shadows Into Light Two', cursive;
```

Comment: I have directly using from google. same as what you have given. it's not working only in windows safari.

Answer (score 0):

Some thin fonts become less readable on white background. If you are using light colour then would it be possible for you to change background colour?

Comment: can not change background colour. it's not working only in windows safari. Others and Mac safari is working fine.