# link blinks while bootstrap slider slides - Bug in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-slider

There is a problem I am facing in my project. I noticed that when the slider slides, the links on page blinks. This is more prominent in ipad.

I checked the bootstrap site on ipad and its happening there as well. 
    http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel
Check out the navigational links on the right on ipad landscape view.

I did not find a solution to this anywhere. I guess not many people noticed it.

I need help with what could be causing this issue and where should I look to solve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `-webkit-font-smoothing`; you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21278020/3088475) for webkit font consistence.