# Font weight is changing on displaying as block

Tags: css, hover, block, fixed, display

I'm trying to create those famous nav bars, but I'm encountering a weird problem...

I've created a JSFiddle that shows my code and my problem : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/92w2rr2z/)

Basically when I'm hovering the "2" menu so that my dropdown-content is displayed as block (previously it was set to none) my whole document `font-weight` is changing...

Two things :

- When I'm setting my .dropdown-content to `display: block` I'm not encountering this problem
- Second when I'm setting my .head1 `position` to anything else than `fixed` I'm not encountering this problem

Thank you in advance for any clue !

**And I forgot to mention but this only happens on Safari...**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding

```
body{
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}
```

to your CSS. Worked for me in Safari when I added it in your JSFiddle.

Please have a look at: [Font weight turns lighter on Mac/Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21278020/font-weight-turns-lighter-on-mac-safari)

Comment: It worked ! Thank you very much, I'll read the link you gave me ! :D