# css Arial Font pixelated on wordpress

Tags: css, font-family

I have read how chrome renders fonts and the differences between other browsers etc. But recently I came up with a interesting scenario.I have two files. One is a wordpress page where the font is used in header. Other is static html page with same code. On static html page the text **Restaurant Appliance Parts** appears smoothly. But same browser and wordpress page the font is pixelated. What could cause this problem?

Here is CSS:

```
font-size: 60px;
line-height: 70px;
font-family: Arial;
```

Here is the image showing the problem.IFyou notice p and n and a you can see pixelated.
[image]
Here is the demo - HTML File:
http://restaurantapplianceparts.com/dev/wp-content/themes/vizio/test.html

Wordpress page: http://restaurantapplianceparts.com/dev/

I am using chrome on windows.

Regards
Ahmar

Comment: I don't see any changes. What is the device resolution ? Can you embed screen shots

Comment: I can appreciate that the font smoothing looks sharper in the live site but Chrome is definitively applying antialising on both sites. I suspect it's just a purely random effect.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I have added the image to the post also. Why the difference in rendering or smoothing when the code is same?

Comment: @DhruvJoshi Image added

Comment: Try the help here- https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95290?hl=en

Comment: Antialiasing is not hard-coded, it's an algorithm. I don't think you can get the same pixel-by-pixel rendering on two different documents. It also never hurts to [have valid HTML](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Frestaurantapplianceparts.com%2Fdev%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) though I don't think that's the reason. (Whatever, I don't have a exact answer, thus why I post this as comment.)

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario but if this is random shouldn't it apply different effect every time page is loaded?Thanks for posting. Can you please vote the question up so others can see?

Comment: @DhruvJoshi Thanks for posting. Can you please vote the question up so others can see?

Comment: Alright, I didn't mean random. I meant "completely different when input data changes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we zoom-in the screen-shots (making sure that we do not resample the images) we can see that both sites display the same font, with the same colour and an appropriate anti-aliasing:

[image: 500%]

I suspect that this is nothing but a visual effect caused by the different decisions taken by the font rendering software when faced with identical texts in different contexts. For instance, the first sample fits exactly in a horizontal baseline but displays more artifacts in vertical lines. But they both look correct solutions to smooth text; it's only that human brain finds one of them more comfortable.

Apparently, there used to be a [-webkit-font-smoothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786829/webkit-font-smoothing-property-has-no-effect-in-chrome) CSS selector in Chrome but it's no longer available.

Comment: I am replacing the heading with image. It seems the correct solution at the moment.