# How to fix google font pixelation issues on safari and chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari, google-font-api

I have used Google font called http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,700,700italic on my website it looks good on Firefox and IE but not at the safari and Google chrome..... Please view the Image....

[Image](http://wpgamechanger.com/pumpwell/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/instruction.jpg)

I want it to be working on each of the browser without any pixelate issue

Requesting your best suggestion...........

Thanks

Comment: Difference in font rendering, try different fonts, also try different font-size, there used to be a css but no longer there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786829/webkit-font-smoothing-property-has-no-effect-in-chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot possibly control how a browser like Chrome renders fonts. You just have control over choosing the best font at best font-size.(Some fonts looks good only at certain font sizes - the font you are using looks good from 50px onward it seems. EDIT:Ah that is a different [issue](http://inodetelic.com/font-anti-aliasing-technique-in-chrome-changes-after-48px-size/))

If you / your client is so specific you can even get help from some custom rendering like

1. [Typeface.js](http://typeface.neocracy.org/)
2. [Cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/)

which uses canvas/flash to render fonts. Using it extensively can cause performance issues or slowness.

There used to a font-smoothening, but I guess no longer supported, you can try it though [-webkit-font-smoothing property has no effect in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786829/webkit-font-smoothing-property-has-no-effect-in-chrome)

Answer (score 1):

Just try this:

```css
{
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0.6px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can smooth fonts by using

```
body {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-smooth