# Safari font rendering issues

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, safari, rendering

As you can see below, the Texta-Light font in Chrome appears completely different with Safari. Chrome displays the font as I like but Safari's rendering on OS X and iOS looks too thin. The Safari image below is taken on iOS and as you can see for some reason the font appears as if there is two bits of text present.

I've looked for a solution but found nothing which works. I tried using `-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;` but according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786829/webkit-font-smoothing-property-has-no-effect-in-chrome?lq=1), the code isn't working anymore.

**Chrome:**

[image: Chrome font-rendering]

**Safari on iOS:**

[image: Safari font-rendering]

Here is the code for the images above:

```
h2 {
    font-family: 'Texta-Light', sans-serif;
    font-size: 3.5em;
    line-height: 1.2em;
}
```

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: if you are using a webfont, check which version (woff, svg, ttf) is actually applied. then try change the order of the `src()`s in the `@font-family` declaration

Comment: Can you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? A screenshot doesn't give us much to go on.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I just added the code for the images.

Comment: That's not quite an MCVE. An example webpage with where we could inspect the text would be more useful.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I've added a website which shows the problem in Safari.

Comment: @RonaldUlyssesSwanson I'm not using any webfonts unfortunately, the font is an .otf

Comment: if you look closly in IOS font, its a font that has been overlayed by a font like it self. chrome also do those overlaying in fonts and use it for adding styles to the font such as "bold". the overlay font of the safari has some bugs I guess where the position or size of the original font and the overlayed font are not the same.

Comment: @GenesisMallari That sounds right, is there anything I can do to solve this, or am I stuck with it? This font issue really damages the consistent UI of the site

Comment: how are you importing the font? try renaming font as .ttf

Comment: I'm using `@font-face {
  font-family: 'Texta-Light';
  src: url('../fonts/Texta-Light.otf');
 }` to import the font. I renamed it to .ttf but saw no change in appearance.

Comment: Please make sure all file type is included ie ttf,otf,woff,eot,svg,woff2 etc for browser supporting.

Comment: Found another setting -webkit-font-feature-settings, which I've added to my answer though your site is down so its hard to test.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Safari has an issue with fonts. The easiest fix for the duplicate text issue is clarifying the font-weight:

```
font-weight: 400;
```

Using Lucho's Javascript's text stroke solution along with specifying font-weight will make your text the same as it is on Chrome.

Comment: This didn't work for me, I'm using the text stroke solution in CSS where I feel I have control over what browser it's displayed in.

Answer (score 23):

There is a CSS property, text-rendering, which in Safari is by default set to optimizeSpeed. What you want to change is:

```
text-rendering:optimizeLegibility;
```

[image]

From https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-rendering/

There are four possible values:

• auto (default) - The browser makes educated guesses about when to optimize for speed, legibility, and geometric precision while drawing text. Be aware that different browsers interpret this value differently.

• optimizeSpeed - The browser emphasizes rendering speed over legibility and geometric precision when drawing text. It disables kerning and ligatures.

• optimizeLegibility - The browser emphasizes legibility over rendering speed and geometric precision. This enables the use of special kerning and optional ligature information that may be contained in the font file for certain fonts.

• geometricPrecision - The browser emphasizes geometric precision over rendering speed and legibility. Certain aspects of fonts—such as kerning—don't scale linearly, so geometricPrecision can make text using those fonts look good. When SVG font is scaled, the browser calculates pixel size, then rounds to the nearest integer. The geometricPrecision property allows for more fluid scaling. Note: Only WebKit browsers apply this fluid value, Gecko treats the value just like optimizeLegibility.

There is an additional setting -webkit-font-feature-settings, of which one of them is kerning:

-webkit-font-feature-settings

```
h2 {
     -webkit-font-feature-settings: "kern" 1;
}
```

Comment: Can anybody confirm this works? It's not making a difference for me, on Safari 10.1.2 on Mac OS X 10.12.6

Comment: Works. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 14):

If, as per your comment, you are only serving `.otf`, you will need to serve the other file types too.

This could be causing an issue to do with iOs as until iOs 4.2, SVG was the only format to use custom fonts on the ipad or iphone.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

A great tool to use is Font Squirrel's [Webfont Generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator)

**Edit:**
Also as mentioned in the comments the `font-weight` is set to `bold` by default and you are loading a `light` font.

Comment: I tried that today, though the issue still remains.

Comment: Did you load the various files in that order? The link to the website in your question no longer works?

Comment: Yes I used that order, I used Font Squirrels Generator too.

Comment: Any chance of updating that link to take a closer look?

Comment: Have you tried setting `font-weight: normal;` to your `@font-face`. The font could be rendering at different weights. Hard for me to test as I can't update your code to see on my iphone but I would suggest it as currently you are serving the 'light' font but the `h2` has browser styling of `bold` by default

Comment: I got a problem with "ts" and "ps" with TTNorms font, using ttf and svg format it solves in iOS, thanks!

Comment: Wow theWebfont generator fixed most of my issues. I was using an very unusual font. Thanks for the kink!

Answer (score 10):

I found [a post which uses JS to adjust the text-stroke property](http://davidlesches.com/blog/making-browsers-play-nice-with-thin-fonts). Here is the actual code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') > -1;
    is_explorer = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') > -1;
    is_firefox = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') > -1;
    is_safari = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") > -1;
    is_opera = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Presto") > -1;
    is_mac = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Mac OS') != -1);
    is_windows = !is_mac;

    if (is_chrome && is_safari){
      is_safari=false;
    }

    if (is_safari || is_windows){
      $('body').css('-webkit-text-stroke', '0.5px');
    }


  });
```

You can modify the text-stroke of some other element.
Hope it helps.

Comment: @Ajean: Please be sure you're not just pattern-matching "I have the same problem" without checking for a solution, which this post includes.

Comment: @NathanTuggy You are correct, I didn't read this carefully enough when reviewing. Thanks for the double check!

Comment: Fantastic answer! This seems to be the only solution which works well.

Comment: Very interesting answer! Completely changes the look of sub-pixel fonts on Safari.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue with font rendering on Safari, the browser couldn't cant find a bold version for the web font so it was trying to copy it which may vary in the bad rendering result.

You can try to disable it by adding: this CSS:

```
font-synthesis: none
```

Otherwise you can try setting the font-weight manually to one which is available ie.

```
font-weight: 400
```

Comment: This was the answer for me.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
html, body {
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
```

or if like that it doesn't work,

```
html, body {
    text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
}
```

Comment: I also saw no difference, I don't think this problem can be fixed at all.

Comment: have you tried with another font? Something like Open Sans https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Open+Sans or Roboto etc...

Comment: Agree. Absolutely no difference (checked screenshot zooms) for me while using .woff fonts in Safari. Safari is the worst of browsers regarding sub pixel rendering. Inconsistent 'u’ or 'n’ renderings in different text lines even in well hinted fonts.

Answer (score 3):

Based on @lucho's answer, I used same approach but I'm applying the fix as soon as `<body>` tag loads. This fixes the issue with too thin Open Sans font in iOS Safari.

```html
<body>
<script>
  (function () {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent
    var isIOSSafari = /iPhone|iPad|iPod/.test(ua) && /AppleWebKit.*Safari\//i.test(ua) && ua.indexOf('Chrome') === -1
    if (isIOSSafari) {
      document.body.style.webkitTextStroke = '.5px'
    }
  })()
</script>
```

**ALTERNATIVE APPROACH:**

Alternatively you can add a class like `ios-safari` to `<html>` tag and then apply CSS to it normally:

```html
  <script>
  (function () {
    const ua = navigator.userAgent
    const isIOSSafari = /iPhone|iPad|iPod/.test(ua) && /AppleWebKit.*Safari\//i.test(ua) && !ua.includes('Chrome')
    if (isIOSSafari) document.documentElement.classList.add('ios-safari')
  })()
  </script>
</head>
```

CSS:

```css
.ios-safari {
  -webkit-text-stroke: .5px;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, I just changed -webkit-text-stroke to -webkit-text-stroke-width since the prior setting requires a colour variable as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Work for me!!!

```
.text{
       font-weight: unset;
       -webkit-text-stroke: thin;
}
```

Try it...!

Comment: Worked for me as well. This, however, will affect the font rendering in Chrome, so it requires some logic (see @Lucho's answer).

Answer (score 0):

A potential tested solution is to increase font-weight by a 100 iOS-wide, using a [feature-query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47818418/1851294) (assuming your default font weight is 400):

```
@supports (-webkit-touch-callout: none) {
  body {
    font-weight: 500;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this approach, which kept he font on Chromium based browsers the same as before and changes only for safari browser.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") == 125) {
        $('body').css('-webkit-text-stroke', 'thin');
    }
});
```