# Text renders unreadable in Safari, while perfect in Chrome

Tags: css, safari, text-rendering

Somehow the text on a specific part on my website renders unreadable on Safari, while it renders normal on Chrome or any other browser. What I find even more strange it that it's random whether text will render unreadable or not. Just refresh your browser and you'll see.

[This is](http://iscs.nl) my website and below you'll find a screenshot of the issue. Left is Safari, right is Chrome.

[image]

I've experimented with `text-rendering` and `transform`, but I couldn't find the issue that permanently fixes it, without creating a problem in Chrome.

Does anyone has a suggestion to help me and perhaps others having this issue?

Comment: have you tried? -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;

Comment: Yes. Doesn't change a thing.

Comment: try -webkit-filter: blur(0) and -webkit-perspective: 1000, I don't have safari so I can't test it myself, sorry :P

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but sadly not working. Doesn't change a thing.. At least, not positively

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safari font rendering issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31056543/safari-font-rendering-issues)