# Custom fonts not getting updated on safari browser

Tags: fonts, safari, font-face, fabricjs, font-family

I am using fabric JS library for creating shapes and adding texts with colors and stroke etc. for text I have some custom fonts which are applied to the texts from dropdown selection. But it is observed on changing fonts on safari nothing happens, sometimes it changes the font and somtimes not untill text is de-selected (by clicking somewhere else) and it changes the font, working fine in mozilla and chrome.

Defintely not a fabric problem but safari rendering issue for fonts.

I have tried:

1. [safari font rendering issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31056543/safari-font-rendering-issues) and also
2. [text-rendering](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-rendering/)

but no luck, can anyone tell what could be the possible reason and what more should I look.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://fabricjs.com/loadfonts)

Comment: Hi,Thanks for reply and the link you shared is working fine better in safari, and I did the same using `FontFaceObserver`, but no luck in safari